# Sms message being sent to multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I've got a report from multiple users getting sent multiple sms verification messages even though they’ve only clicked the button once.

The code below is what handles that part (controller):

```
def sms
  current_user.generate_sms_code!
  current_user.sms
end
```

The model :

```
def generate_sms_code!
  range = (10000..99999).to_a
  update_attribute :sms_code, range[rand(range.length)]
end

def sms
  TWILIO_CLIENT.account.sms.messages.create(
    :from => TWILIO_SMS_NUMBER,
    :to => self.phone,
    :body => "Please confirm! Your verification code is: #{sms_code}"
  )
end
```

Maybe I need to do something in the back end around time since last sent? Any ideas how to solve this or what to do to prevent the sending of multiple sms to same user?

**Details :**

I'm debouncing on the front end.

Comment: I think you should use a method like update_Sms_change(anthing) ,and call it on your update action from user_Controller instead of update_attribute callback, may it will work

Comment: Are you debouncing your javascript buttons, as this is almost certainly the cause of the problem.

Comment: @mcfinnigan I'm debouncing, that was my first reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend that you record all SMS messages in the database for future reference.  This will also allow you to see if someone's already been sent a particular message in the last X minutes or whatever, and so block repeated messages.  Of course you should still find out why the repeated message is being sent in the first place, but this provides a safety net at least.

A few years ago I did an app that sent out SMS messages.  This was the schema for my Message class, which represented sent SMS messages:

```
create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "to_number"     #the phone number
  t.datetime "sent_at"
  t.boolean  "successful"
  t.text     "kind"          #a short string from a predefined list - "welcome", "daily_reminder", "task_complete" etc
end
```

You should move all of the SMS sending functionality into the SMS class, so that your controller code might look something like this:

```
@sms = @user.messages.create(:body => "Welcome to MyApp.com")
@sms.deliver
```

There's a few different ways you could go about blocking repeated messages.  One way is to make the message invalid if there has been one sent recently, and make sure that the .deliver method won't send unsaved messages (it won't get saved if it's invalid).  eg

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :not_a_repetition

  def not_a_repetition
    if Message.where(["user_id = ? and body = ? and id <> ? and sent_at > ?", self.user_id, self.body, self.id, 1.hour.ago]).any?
      self.errors.add(:body, "has already been sent recently")
    end
  end

  def deliver
    return false if self.new_record?
    #code for filling in any necessary fields (eg to_number) and sending the SMS here
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution:

You could add an `last_message_sent_at` attribute to the `User` model and refuse to send another message if `last_message_sent` is less then 1 minute (arbitrary) ago.

Comment: I'd recommend something like this too, although you should have a table of sent sms records (eg with a SentSms model), which you can query to see if the same message has been sent out recently, instead of adding a new field to the User schema.  You will need this data anyway for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @MaxWilliams what would be the reason behind adding additional model to that app? instead of just adding column to hold the timestamp information?

Comment: At some point, you or someone else is going to want to know if a particular sms was sent out on such and such a day.  If you don't make a db record every time you send an sms out then you won't be able to answer the question.

Comment: @Max Williams can you please post an answer like you comment, I think I'm gonna go with new model and database table